# If $A$ is a subset of $(V,\| \cdot \|)$, where $V$ is a vector space. Let $\overline{A}$ denote closure. Show $\overline{x + A} = x + \overline{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Let $A$ a subset of $(V,\| \cdot \|)$, where $V$ is a vector space. Let $\overline{A}$ denote closure of $A$. Show that if $x \in V$ then $\overline{x + A} = x + \overline{A}$.

---

**Attempt:**

$(\Rightarrow)$ Consider $y \in \overline{x + A} = (x + A) \cup (x + A)'$ where $(x + A)'$ is the set of limit points.
$$ \Rightarrow \quad y \in x + A \quad \textrm{or} \quad y \in (x + A)'$$

*Scenario 1:* $y \in x + \overline{A}$ (in which case we are done).

*Scenario 2:* $ y \in x'$ and $y \in A'$.

Continuing with Scenario 2:
Since $y \in x'$ but $x'$ is just an element which means $y = x = \overline{x}$. Since $y \in A'$ this means $y \in \overline{A}$.
Therefore $y \in x + \overline{A}$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $y \in x + \overline{A}$.

Then $y = x$ and $y \in A \cup A'$

This means: $y \in x + A$ and $y \in x + A'$.

*Scenario 1:* $y \in x + A$. If this is the case we are done because $x + A \subset \overline{x + A}$.

*Scenario 2:* $y \in x + A'$. This means $y = x$ and $y \in A'$. Which means $y\ = x = \overline{x}$ and $y \in A'$ means $y \in \overline{A}$. Which implies $y \in \overline{x + A}$.

---

**Comment:** I may be overthinking thing a bit, but I don't really think this is the right way to answer this problem. I never used the notion of norm given to me and I feel that does have a key part to play. Feedback on my approach ?

Comment: What do you mean $y\in x'$? $x'$ is not a set.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree, I was more so conveying the idea that the set of limit points of a point is the point itself.

Comment: It is not generally true that if $A$ and $B$ are sets then $\overline{A+B}=\overline{A}+\overline{B}.$ Specifically, you can have $A,B$ closed but $A+B$ is not. An example of this is $A=\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid xy=-1\}.$ Then $A,B$ are closed and $(0,0)$ is a limit point of $A+B,$ but it is not in $A+B.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to show that  $y\in \overline{x+A}$ if and only if $y-x\in\overline{A}.$

If $y-x\in\overline{A}$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $\|y-x-a\|<\epsilon.$ But then letting $a'=x+a\in x+A,$ we have for any $\epsilon>0$ an $a'\in x+A$ such that  $\|y-a'\|<\epsilon,$ so $y\in \overline{x+A}.$

On the other hand, if $y\in \overline{x+A}$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a'\in x+A$ with $\|y-a'\|<\epsilon.$ then letting $a=a'-x\in A$ we have, for any $\epsilon>0$ an $a\in A$ such that $\|y-x-a\|=\|y-a'\|<\epsilon.$ So $y-x\in \overline{A}.$

---

From the comments, there is some confusion, perhaps because the readers do not know this lemma:

> **Lemma:** If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $A\subseteq X,$ then we have that $x\in\overline A$ if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)<\epsilon.$

If $x\in A,$ and any $\epsilon>0,$ you can choose $a=x\in A$ and get $d(x,a)=0<\epsilon.$

If $x\in A',$ then you can use the definition of limit point to prove this.

On the other hand, we need to show that if $x$ satisfies the $\epsilon$ statement for all $\epsilon>0$ then $x\in\overline{A}=A\cup A'.$

If $x\in A$ then $x\in\overline{A},$ so we only need to check that the cases where $x\not\in A,$ then show the $\epsilon$ statement implies $x\in A'.$

Comment: I'm a little confused about your solution. To show that an element is contained in one of the sets you are using the idea of open balls. But how do we deal with the limit points? Since this is the closure this is a closed set so there couldn't be $\epsilon$ - nrighbourhoods around those points that would still be in the set.

Comment: I have to agree with @dc3rd. The statement "If $y-x\in\overline{A}$ then for any $\epsilon >0$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $\|y-x-a\|<\epsilon$" is not sound. You cannot choose an epsilon before choosing an element.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "you cannot choose an epsilon before choosing an element." @Zeta-Squared That is, in fact, exactly what we do in this sort of proof.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that you could consider.

Let $x$ be a fixed element of $V$, the function $f:V\to V$ defined by 
$$
f(y) := y+x
$$
is continuous and has a continuous inverse $f^{-1}(y) = y-x$. This means that $f$ is a homeomorphism so 
$$
\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline A).
$$
Unpacking the notation gives $\overline{x + A} = x + \overline{A}$ as you want.

**Edit:** I should also have mentioned that we used the fact that $h(\overline A) \subset \overline{h(A)}$ if $h$ is continuous to get the conclusion (apply this fact to $f$ and $f^{-1}$).

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $x+A=x+A$, so it suffices to check that $(x+A)'=x+A'$ to prove that $\overline{x+A}=x+\overline{A}$.

Consider a convergent sequence $(a_{n})\in A$. We have the limit $a\in A'$ and $x+a\in x+A'$, so $\|x+a_{n}-x-a\|\rightarrow 0$. This implies that $x+a$ is the limit of a sequence $(x+a_{n})$ in $(x+A)$. So $x+A'\subseteq(x+A)'$.

Now, consider a sequence $(x+a_{n})$ with limit $(x+a)\in(x+A)'$. We need to show that $a\in A'$. We have $\|a_{n}-a\|=\|x-a_{n}-x-a\|\rightarrow 0$. Therefore $a\in A'$ and so $x+a\in x+A'$. Hence $(x+A)'=x+A'$ and our conclusion follows.